# Prevent scheduled process from running in a "On Lead Creation" process workflowm, based on record change

Tags: process-builder

I have a process workflow that starts when a Lead is created. It's job is to update certain fields in the record every 24 hours for 7 days, starting the day after the process was created, unless it's deactivated by a user (by checking a checkbox in the record). At which point the workflow should no longer trigger.

As stated in this article : https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_limits_scheduled_processing.htm&type=5

"For processes that start when a record is created, Salesforce never reevaluates the record associated with that process. The scheduled time for the actions stays the same, even if the record no longer meets the associated criteria when the scheduled actions are executed."

This leads me to believe that this process will trigger every day for 7 days, regardless of the user updating the record (the tick a checkbox indicated the process should not run).

How can I prevent the processes running once a user has explicitly updated a record to indicate that it should no longer run?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look into using workflow time-based actions (instead of process scheduled actions)?

Those DO respect the criteria evaluation when they are set to fire.

If your usecase does not require the several node processing or multiple child records to update, you are better off with workflows in this case.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workflow_time_dependent.htm&type=5

Comment: Thanks for this. For items that need to exist in the Process Builder, would a workaround be to have the "on creation" trigger invoke another process, then have the scheduled actions within that invoked process? As this process is invoked only once would it re-evaluate the scheduled actions criteria each time?

Comment: Replying to my own comment - The above assertion is true. Having a "on record creation" workflow process invoke another process means the invoked process does not consider itself as being triggered by a record being created and will always evaluate the criteria defined for the action groups within it.